# AndroidStudio -> How to ignore my Library Manifest and use only my Application Manifest?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-library, manifest-merging

I have a AndroidStudio Project imported from Eclipse. In Eclipse i have a library project with his own dummy manifest which i use for testing the library disabling the library checkbox from the project configuration.

Now i want to do the same in AndroidStudio, i want to have the possibility to test my library project with his dummy test manifest but i want that the new manifest-merger ignores my library manifest when compiling my application (that has a dependency with my library project)

How can this be achieved in AndroidStudio?

Thanks

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335889/how-ignore-minsdkversion-of-ligrary-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Gradle in android studio. In your build.gradle file add this:

```
android{
    sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: in which of three gradles? library, application or project?

Comment: You have to add it to the application gradle. Just try removing or renaming the library's gradle.

Comment: i dont understand you. Application gradle does not have a android node, and i thought that removing library gradle is not a good practice because library will need it if i try to execute library in the future